# Azure Workbook - This item is currently hidden so it is not automatically updating

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have an Azure Workbook that uses two parameters.  The report has been working fine with these for the past 10 days.  Today, I updated the parameter values.

There are three groups in the workbook.  The second group does not display any data after changing the two parameters.  The first parameter is a Time Range; the second is a text value.  The other groups do display data that are driven by these parameters.  They update correctly.

When I click "edit" and then click "edit" for the second group that is not displaying, I see my grids and that they have data.  There is a striped overlay however on the grids and there is a message "This item is currently hidden so it is not automatically updating."

Why is the second group -- which has two grids and a chart -- all marked as hidden?  I've checked the properties under Settings, Advanced settings, etc.  "Lazy" is the load type set for the visualizations in group two.

It's very confusing.

I am using the Time Range parameter with an end value that is set in the future, but this doesn't seem to be a problem with the other grids in the other groups.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: without seeing the exact workbook content, hard to say.  As far as i know we haven't changed any behaviors here.  did someone change the names of parameters/etc?  simplest way to help is to post the workbook json content from advanced mode

Comment: @JohnGardner I ended up Editing the group box... and then fiddled with the "Show expand / collapse in title of group" checkbox.  It is now currently checked and began working again.  I've cleared my browser cache and frankly, have no idea what caused it to start working again.  I cannot post content here w/o causing issues with employer.  I would just advise anyone to check the group settings if this happens to you.